# CKEditor's click event not firing

Tags: events, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.4.3 and trying to listen to an editor's click event:

```
editor.on('click', function (e) {
      console.log('click event from attaching to the editor');
});
```

For some reason, the click event never fires. However, if I listen to the `doubleclick` event, it fires when the editor is double clicked.

I was previously listening to the click event on `editor.editable`, but it doesn't appear to work for editors that are not inlined. Why is the `click` event not working?

Some further investigations:

Attaching the event handler on `editor.document` fires for every click, including clicks outside the editor.

Attaching the event handler to `editor.container` fires for clicks on the container including the toolbars.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/295PE/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way of attaching listeners to the editable element in CKEditor:

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var editable = editor.editable();
    editable.attachListener( editable, 'click', function() {
        // ...
    } );
} );
```

Read more about the reasons why `contentDom` event has to be used instead of e.g. [`instanceReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-instanceReady) in [`editable.attachListener` documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener).

Comment: The current documentation does not contain the string `instanceReady`. Could you attach some documentation to the answer directly?

Answer (score 2):

Use attach the event handler to the editor's `editable`. This needs to be done after the editor is ready:

```
editor.on('instanceReady', function (e) {
    editor.editable().on('click', function (event) {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8fZpz/

Comment: Switch between modes and your listener will be list. See [`editable.attachListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener) docs.

Comment: @Reinmar That's a better solution. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @F21 +1 for fiddle, Thnks a lot