# Input onclick function not called

Tags: ckeditor

To test buttons behavior I created a plugin which inserts an input element of type="button" in the editors text. Finally when I click on that inserted button an alert should popup. While the input element is inserted as expected, the alert() is never called. Weird though, the alert() is called shortly before the element is inserted. This is the function which will be fired when the command is executed

```
...
exec: function( editor ) {
var linkHtml = '<input type="button" value='+"click me"+' onclick="'+alert("hello you clicked a button")+'"></input>';
var linkElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(linkHtml, editor.document);
editor.insertElement(linkElement);
}
...
```

Any hints what happens here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var linkHtml = '<input type="button" value='+"click me"+' onclick="'+alert("hello you clicked a button")+'"></input>';
```

This code:

1. Creates a string `'<input type="button" value='+"click me"+' onclick="'`
2. **Executes** `alert("hello you clicked a button")` and append result of it to the previous string. So that `alert()` got executed immediately.
3. Appends `'"></input>'` to the previous string.

So the correct code would be:

```
var linkHtml = '<input type="button" value='+"click me"+' onclick="alert(\'hello you clicked a button\')"></input>';
```

However, CKEditor transforms all `on*` attributes when processing content, because they should not be executed while editing. So if you want to make the `<input>` clickable inside the editor, then you need to do it differently. See this question [CKEditor's click event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989766/ckeditors-click-event-not-firing).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I attached now :  

editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
 var editable = editor.editable();
 editable.attachListener( editable, 'click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
 } );
} );

The clicks are now captured and forwarded. But how to retrieve the element object and its attributes like value ?