# getAttribute() inside an attachedListener function() returns 'null' (CKEditor 4.4.8)

Tags: ckeditor

In a plugin I insert input elements of type "button". I give the elements data attributes. For testing purposes its called "data-test". Further on I attach a listener as recommended in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989766/ckeditors-click-event-not-firing). When I click the button the function() is called. Inside the function() I need to retrieve the "data-test" attribute for further actions.

But the getAttribute('data-test') returns null.
So I guess the variable "linkElement" does not hold the customer attributes.

Any hints how to reference the data attributes correctly ?

....

```
var buttonElement = '<input  type="button"  value="click me"  data-test="test attribute"></input>';
var linkElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(buttonElement, editor.document);
editor.insertElement(linkElement);

// attach listener to capture clicks
editor.editable().attachListener( linkElement, 'click', function() {
                            var attribute = linkElement.getAttribute('data-test');
                            ...
                            console.log('attribute = ',attribute);
                }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question myself because the problem is solved. Or better to say it dissapeared. Neither I can say where it was coming from nor why its gone. Its a bit weird but it may has been a coding problem somewhere in the long chain of neverending JavaScripts. Anyway while days ago the custom attributes were not retrievable, they are now. The code above works perfect. I tested it with FireFox, Chrome and Safari on a Mac. All latest version.