# Listening for click event within CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I've been reading about how to listen for click events within the CKEditor, specifically: [CKEditor's click event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989766/ckeditors-click-event-not-firing) which was answered by Reinmar, but I still can't get this working.

My scenario is I have a CKEditor instance. Paragraphs are enclosed with `<p>` tags, but I enclose parts of the text within `<span>` tags, the content looks like:

```
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p>This is <span>The second paragraph</span></p>
```

I want to add a click event, so whenever a user clicks on the text within a span tag, it performs an action, I'm happy with just getting an alert to display for the time being.

This is my code that I've been trying. I've been [working through the documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable) on the `editable()` `element`, `editor` and `document` properties / methods.

```
_instance.on('contentDom', function () {

    let editable = _instance.editable();
    let elements = new CKEDITOR.dom.element(editable.getElementsByTag('span'));
    console.log(elements);

    editable.attachListener(elements, 'click', function () {
        alert('test');
        console.log("click event");
    });
});
```

The results of the `console.log(elements)` correctly logs the following:

[image: console log result]

and from reading the documentation, the `attachListener()` method requires the first argument to be an instance of `CKEDITOR.dom.element`, so I'm passing the correct arguments, but nothing is alerted or logged when I click on the span tags.

I'm not sure how to proceed to any help would be appreciated.

### Edit

If I replace `editable.attachListener(elements...)` with `editable.attachListener(editable...)` it works as expected, but works whenever I click anywhere within the editor, not specifically span tags, which doesn't really help me that much.

Comment: Do you want the event to fire when *any* `span` is clicked or only those that are (direct) children of a `p`?

Comment: Any span will do, we only accept `<p>`, `<strong>` and `<span>` tags

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Phil. I don't have my CKE files to hand so I'll post this as a comment for now. This should work if you change your listener to the following: `editable.attachListener(editable,"click",function(event){if(event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()==="span")console.log("click event");});`.

Answer (score 0):

By default in current versions of CKEditor span's are not in the allowedContent config, so it might be stripped after you output those elements. I have a simple example here where i output the element name of the clicked element within the editor:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("txtarea");
editor.on("instanceReady", function(evt) {
  evt.editor.editable().on('click', function (event) {
      // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
      console.log("element clicked: ", event.data.$.target);
  });
});
```

If i switch to source and add span and then jump out of source again it is being stripped!

See full example here: http://run.plnkr.co/paYzYa25kt6wFM1J/